# List control to open view from the sidebar

Tags: android, ios

I am looking for the control like I shown in the rounded option in the attached below image on my Android and iOS application. When we click on this option, it opens the view on the right side and closes vice versa.

[image]

Could someone guide me, what is the name of this control, how to implement this control and open view clicking on this on Android as well as iOS? Is it a native behaviour or custom?

Thank you!

Comment: In Android it's called `Sidebar Navigation`.

Comment: Its navigation drawer ,check out the link.
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html.

Comment: thank you all! Also, please mention what is it for iOS?

Comment: For ios only search this in google there are lot's of demo code for slideview  search this word "slide view controller github"

Comment: I downloaded NavigationDrawer from developer.android link. I am trying to import in Eclipse now, Eclipse->Import->Existing projects into workspace->Select root directory of NavigationDrawer. But, it doesn't allow me to 'Next and Finish' the import.